# php operator without spaces

Tags: php, e-commerce

I have this shopkeeper running in Wordpress. And I want to change the colon to parentheses but it gets weird , I don't want spaces between it just like this " (€5,50).

I've been trying to fix this problem for almost a day.

really hope to see any answers.

here is the html : gyazo.com/f05c00f01d2522aa962d90f5c0fcc5ea

method function :

```
function wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) {
    $label = $method->label;

    if ( $method->cost > 0 ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $label .= '(' . wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() ).')';
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        }
    } elseif ( $method->id !== 'free_shipping' ) {
        $label .= ' (' . __( 'Free', 'woocommerce' ) . ')';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', $label, $method );
}
```

code where I print :

```
            <select name="shipping_method[<?php echo $index; ?>]" data-index="<?php echo $index; ?>" id="shipping_method_<?php echo $index; ?>" class="shipping_method">
                <?php foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $method->id ); ?>" <?php selected( $method->id, $chosen_method ); ?>><?php echo wp_kses_post( wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems more an CSS issue, show the generated html of the image. Also have alook here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_price.html#400-433

Comment: here the html : https://gyazo.com/9aeaacfa2219a44c5b60eb45d01d3cec

Comment: @johnsmith I don't see any price in your HTML. How about you add the relevant piece of markup to your question or use some kind of pastebin instead?

Comment: For some clarity, the HTML above seems to be the right section, but it's for free shipping. We would need to see the HTML _of a price_ as that's what you're having issues with.

Comment: @LukeBriggs, ,  sorry wrong file , heres the right file : https://gyazo.com/f05c00f01d2522aa962d90f5c0fcc5ea

Comment: @domdom heres the right file  : gyazo.com/f05c00f01d2522aa962d90f5c0fcc5ea

Comment: @LukeBriggs already tried in css , still the same thing.

Comment: @johnsmith we're not getting enough information to be able to help out - try making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I just edit the example , added the print code

Comment: @johnsmith you have a CSS problem though; we need to be able to see the relevant selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Before the result try to add this:

```
$label = '(&euro;'.preg_replace("/\([\s]+?/", "", str_replace(array('&euro;', '&nbsp;'), '', $label));
```

First use str_replace to remove html entities, seconds use a regex to remove all whitespaces after the ( and finally append at the start of the string "(€"

Comment: what do I have to put inside the (&euro;)

Comment: Nothing to put INTO the (&euro;) what do you mean?

Comment: this is what I get now the euro is a string : https://gyazo.com/7d002f04a75d23d3d5caeea92553f05d